# Should I improve the title of an obvious duplicate? If so, how do I make it more unique?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, title

I found a question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537659/employee-data-vb-net)), which is an obvious duplicate of many existing "How do I read a text file in VB.NET" questions (e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358290/read-a-text-file-in-vb)).

I've voted for *this one* to be a duplicate of *that one*, and I wanted to change the (utterly useless) title of *this one* from "Employee data, vb.net" to the more descriptive "How to read data from a text file". This yielded the following error message:

[image: error message]

I can't be more specific, because the question **is** exactly the same as a lot of other questions on this site, and the fact that the user wants to read "employee data" is completely irrelevant.

Should I just leave the title of the duplicate question alone? Or should I rename it to something like "How to read data from a text file (yet another duplicate #*some number*)"?

Somehow, that feels like cheating the system, so I'm wondering if there is a best practice recommendation for such cases.

Comment: Interesting question, I'm curious what the community thinks about this. If it were me, I'd just leave it alone. It is not a particularly useful duplicate anyway (e.g., as a pointer to the master question for future Googlers), so polishing the title seems like a waste of time.

Comment: I suspect that's exactly what happened when the OP posted his question, he then went for the useless title to get it submit it anyway.   Instead of searching for existing answers.  Of which there are a *lot*, we really don't need this question so editing the title isn't useful either.  We'll get it deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks for the edit, the title is much more to the point now!

Comment: I'd probably reinsert the otherwise useless 'employee' ("How to read employee data from a text file") to make the title distinct.  And, of course, make sure that the body is clean and clear as well.

Comment: When I get the "a question with that title already exists" popup, I usually abandon editing a question altogether. It's a retarded popup that should not show for certain users, say > 2K rep. There are only so many unique titles about the same problem you can think of. I am of course talking about questions that are salvageable, and obviously duplicates are part of those, as they stay on the site (hence must have a proper title).

Comment: The real problem here is that many duplicate questions are worthless

Comment: One thing to note, that apart from spelling mistakes and obviously useless titles, "weird" and "oddly formulated" titles of duplicates can actually help people find the canonical question when they also use that "weird" phrasing in their search query. (Which is a typical use case for keeping duplicates around.) - So don't be *too* quick in "improving" a title, as the "lesser" titles *can* serve a purpose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Should I improve the title of an obvious duplicate?

If it won't get deleted, especially if it looks like an otherwise useful sign-post, and thus shouldn't be deleted anyway:
Sure, go for it.

Just remember that part of its value as a duplicate, if it has that, might be in the original title.

> If so, how do I make it unique?

Try to base it on the original title and try to describe things differently from all the existing duplicates. Remember that titles are prime real estate for searching, titles containing the same key-words or irrelevant ones don't make it a better sign-post. Aside from that general advice, you are mostly on your own deciding how to get it done and whether it's possible at all, sorry.

Comment: Does it not enter the reopen que like this?, does it not blow OP chance to improve question before it enters?, maybe a note in your answer if its already closed?

Comment: Deduplicator, great name.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I improve the title of an obvious duplicate?

I say yes, for many reasons:

- sometimes users land on the duplicate question and not the duplicated one, so it's worth improving its title and content.
- OP can learn from that edit and can improve his future posts.
- the question might be not duplicate after OP edits it and better explains what his problem.

> If so, how do I make it unique?

Good question. I don't think there's a general answer for it, but surely I discourage adding something like "*(yet another duplicate #some number)*" - this will pollute the website and might make it harder to be found via search engines. "Cheating" the system can be done in a good manner, you can always find alternatives for titles: "How do I open..", "How to open..", "Opening a file in..".

Answer (score 3):

I think adding the programming language explicitly in the title would be useful for such a generic issue, but there are literally dozens of ways to express the same thing, without using the exact same words.

So, I would change it into any of these :

- `How to read a text file using vb.net`
- `How to read a text file in vb.net`
- `How to read a text file with vb.net`
- `How to read data from a text file using vb.net`
- `How to read data from a text file in vb.net`
- `How to read data from a text file with vb.net`
- `Reading a text file using vb.net`
- `Reading a text file in vb.net`
- `Reading a text file with vb.net`
- ...

On the other hand, this particular question appears to have been deleted, so it would have been a waste of time to change the title.

---

#### Notes :

In the comments to my answer, [**CodeCaster**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) argued that (1) programming languages should be mentioned as tags and that (2) tag content should not be explicitly mentioned in the title, using [**this question on meta**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) as a reference for the latter. Thus, he argues, you should not put the programming language in the title.

While I guess there are valid arguments to apply this to some questons, I don't think this should be applied to all questions as a general principle, for the following reasons :

- While I guess checking the tags of a question could remove ambiguity whenever the title is unclear, I do think it's horrible [**UX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) to have to check the tag whenever encountering questions as generic as `How to read a text file`, `How to read define a variable`, `How to create a class`, etc. where there's not even a remote chance of correctly guessing the programming environment just from looking at the title. Why do I have to check the tag each and every time to clarify something that could be clear just from looking at the title?!
- Consider the question [**trying to create a css transition effect on menus using php and results from database**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576063/trying-to-create-a-css-transition-effect-on-menus-using-php-and-results-from-dat) that I just stumbled upon. What (if anything at all) is gained, really, by removing the CSS and PHP references from the title and turning it into something like **Trying to create a transition effect on menus using results from a database**? Even in a cases like this (where I could reasonable guess the environment), I personally think that all removing the CSS and PHP references would do is make it less obvious for someone like me to decide whether to click the question and see if I can answer it, making it more likely for me to just ignore it completely. Isn't that the very opposite of what we're supposed to be going for?
- And last but not least, tags aren't always visible whenever a title is visible. For example, consider the "Linked questions" and "Related questions" on the right hand side of any question. Or what about search results on Google? Here, tags aren't even shown at all. So all you have to go with to figure out whether a question is relevant for you is the title. Do you really want to waste my precious time and that of so many others on this website by encouraging us to click on questions that involve programming environments I'm completely unfamiliar with, where this could have simply been avoided simply by mentioning a programming language? From a UX perspective, that is about as horrible as it gets!

Here's what Jeff Atwood himself has to say on this issue :

> Consider the following question titles with the tag [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) in
> the title.
>
> 1. Python: How do I tell what OS I am running on?
> 2. Python - How do I tell what OS I am running on?
> 3. How do I tell what OS I am running on in Python?
> 4. How do I tell what OS Python is running on?
> 5. [Python] How do I tell what OS I am running on?
>
> Only #5 is objectionable enough for us to automate its removal. #3 and #4 are *explicitly encouraged*. #1 and #2 are ... not really a problem so long as they are not happening "too often".
>
> It is the **ritual and systemic** use of tags in this manner that I
> object to, not the mere presence of it at all.
>
> [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them/105991#105991)

Comment: Nope, languages are tags, and in general you shouldn't use those in your title.

Comment: @CodeCaster : Personally, I'm more likely to click a question if I can at least guess the programming language based on the title... and I'm pretty sure I'm not unique here. With issues this generic, you simply can't expect to know the programming language at all just from reading the title... so IMO the programming language should be mentioned in the title explicitly, to avoid people clicking on a question that involves a programming environment people are unfamiliar with.

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). The language will be mentioned in the tags.

Comment: @CodeCaster : Tags are not shown for eg. "related questions" or "linked questions", which often brings me to questions I don't care about whenever the programming language cannot be guessed from the title or isn't mentioned in the title. IMO, that's just horrible user experience!

Comment: The entire "releated" section is horrible and rarely ever relevant, but that's no reason to go and include tags in titles and an entirely different story altogether.

Comment: As for your edit, you're now making a case for adding (language) tags to titles, please do so in your own discussion question, not in an answer to an only slightly related question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Heh heh, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317393/allow-editors-to-submit-duplicate-titles/317471#comment312251_317471

Comment: @BoltClock oh, you.

Comment: @CodeCaster : I added a *notes* section at the bottom of my answer to clarify my position on the matter.

Comment: @CodeCaster : I just learnt that our great & fearless leader (Jeff Atwood) agrees with me on and even explicitly encourages the use of the programming language in the title if it doesn't come off as articifial and serves a purpose. See the last edit to my answer for a quote (with source reference)

Comment: Slapping on "in $language" in order to circumvent a retarded system doesn't really make for better question titles. Furthermore I'll refer you to my [previous comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317364/should-i-improve-the-title-of-an-obvious-duplicate-if-so-how-do-i-make-it-more/317485?noredirect=1#comment312331_317485) that I don't wish to continue this discussion under a merely slightly related question.

Comment: @CodeCaster : Google search results don't show tag info either. Are they also "a retarded system"? Anyway, I rest my case, as a statement by Jeff Atwood himself pretty much settles the issue.

Comment: Yes, I think this rigorous anti-duplicate-title check is not that smart. Also, tags are prefixed in the `<title>` element. And a five year old answer by someone who [doesn't actively participate in the site at all anymore since four years](http://blog.codinghorror.com/farewell-stack-exchange/) doesn't mean quite that much, opinions and practices change over time.

Comment: @CodeCaster : `a five year old answer by someone who doesn't actively participate in the site at all...` — You do know that Jeff Atwood is a **co-founder** of Stack Overflow, right? Even though he left Stack Exchange in 2012 to spend more time with his family, he and Spolsky continued publishing a weekly podcast covering the progress on Stack Exchange until 2014, and Atwood it still consider an authority on any matters related to Stack Exchange to this day by pretty much anyone AFAIK.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that everything he ever said is set in stone, forever. I can tell you exactly what's wrong with slapping "in $language" onto a title, but I won't, because this is not a discussion question about that subject. It is a very nice workaround for the particular issue being discussed here, but it doesn't make for great titles - and that's all I want to say about it right now.

Comment: @CodeCaster : There's so many issues that could be improved / fixed on Stack Overflow that I could write an entire series of blog posts about it. However, I don't believe that people adding `in $language`  for questions **where they add relevant context** is one of those issues. I also believe that one of its co-founders making the very same argument back in 2011 pretty much settles the issue, even though that was 5 years ago. The argument made by Atwood and myself was 100% valid back in 2011 and I know of no reason that makes it less valid today. Anyway, **let's just agree to disagree here!**

Answer (score -1):

The point of keeping a dupe around (they don't get auto deleted like other close reasons) is that the title/body of the dupe acts as a sign post to point to the dupe target. If the title of the dupe is the same as the dupe target, there's no point in having the sign post anymore. but... if the title is just complete garbage (as with this case), maybe the question should just be deleted because it's not a good sign post.

As Kevin B posted a comment down ,I will have to agree with him for his logical reasoning

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to leave it alone. You think that the question is a duplicate. And you also think that the title of the question is poorly worded. Two beliefs, each with validity.

But one of these beliefs is stronger than the other, because if the question is a duplicate, it will be "dealt with". The implication is that a duplicate question does not have value. Thus, the poorly worded title is a moot point. You think it's the same as an existing question so the duplicate can be closed and in the future, people will be directed to the existing question.

Furthermore, I think to change the title would only make it more difficult for other people to disagree with you that it's not a duplicate. This is not really an issue in your example, but we are not always perfect when we think two questions are the same, maybe they are slightly different and thus both have value. What if you modify the question you think is a duplicate (but isn't), but once you modified it, it becomes a duplicate?

This question is not directly addressed in the FAQ for duplicate questions, But several related points are. [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Edit: The duplicate questions don't have value, but the answers might...

Comment: _"The implication is that a duplicate question does not have value"_ - they do, especially when they use different phrasing than the one they are a duplicate of, so people who search on _those_ terms will find the duplicated question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just paraphrasing the link. When they discuss questions that seem similar but aren't actually duplicates: _"It's rarely this straightforward, however -- usually there are two similar but not-quite-the-same questions, both of which have value for different reasons."_

Comment: The question _here_ is about a question that _is_ a duplicate, but with a less-than-perfect title. Merely changing the title does not change the fact that it is a duplicate.

Comment: In my impression, a duplicate is closed because it does not have value, in the sense of adding information that did not exist previously on StackOverflow. It simply duplicates another question, so it's to maximize value, just redirect everyone to the same place. The question doesn't have value, but some of the answers might, so in that case, flag the question and moderators can merge it to preserve the information. I fail to see how changing the title to become even more like other questions will add any information.

Comment: A duplicate question is closed because the **answers it will attract will be duplicates** of answers that already exist under another question. A duplicate question is kept visible because there may be different terminology, so people who use that terminology in searching, will find the duplicate question it links to. Also, what you seem to assume, the OP here is **not** asking to change the title of the newer question to the one it duplicates, but just to _anything else_ than the current title ("Employee data, vb.net"), so it actually resembles the problem being described in the question.

Comment: I think you see my point. The title shouldn't be touched because it's from a newbie who didn't know how to search, but its impreciseness can help others by nature of its aberration.

Comment: No, I do not see your point. "Employee data, vb.net" is not a helpful title for anyone. The title is also far from the only thing that search engines index.

Comment: Oh well, I can't compete with your edited comment. Your perspective seems to be that we should edit duplicate questions until they become more similar to the questions that have already been answered many times before, but the way I see it, that only decreases the potential value of the repetition.

Comment: Nowhere am I saying that. You seem to think that "editing a question's title" and "voting to close as duplicate" are mutually exclusive, which I'm saying they aren't. The question's title was utter crap (I'll repeat it once more for you: "Employee data, vb.net") and must be improved so it actually describes what the question is about (for example "Reading a text file"). Performing that edit is perfectly valid.

Comment: "Reading a text file" has been asked a billion times and has no value. Please delete the question from the site. Thanks, it has been deleted! Negative value questions just drag us down.

Comment: "Should obviously duplicate questions be deleted from the site" is an entirely different question.

Answer (score -4):

In common case, you should NOT. Titles are used for searching so unchanged title should help more people to find solution as they are searching for other words which are not used in the canonical question.

But in this specific case, the original title is absolutely useless, so it would be goog to change it. What about "Reading of a text file", "Reading the text file", "Data reading from the text file"? You don't need to fully copy that title.

Comment: In general, you SHOULD. Most people are notoriously bad at coming up with a proper title.

Comment: @CodeCaster, you should fix any bad title. But you should not update the title just because it's a duplicate question.

Comment: Nowhere am I saying anything like that. I'm saying most titles are crap, and most proper titles have already been used.

Comment: I have to agree with this answer, to an extent. The point of keeping a dupe around (they don't get auto deleted like other close reasons) is that the title/body of the dupe acts as a sign post to point to the dupe target. If the title of the dupe is the same as the dupe target, there's no point in having the sign post anymore. but... if the title is just complete garbage (as with this case), maybe the question should just be deleted because it's not a good sign post.

Comment: @Kevin B Your comment would make a good(the best)  answer.

Comment: @chux just realized that my comment basically mirrors Deduplicator's answer.

Comment: Very often, there are typos in question titles, and when you want to fix those, you get an error that the title (without typos) is already used for another question. So I’m being stopped from fixing a typo in a title…