# Suggested edits review - "Another question exists"

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I just came across this [suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17427174).

Notice the original title of the question:

> SpringBoot and Html: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Given that it had tags in the title, I decided to remove them. But when I tried I got this error:

[image]

> A question with that title already exists; please be more specific.

Which is a good validation when someone is posting a new question as it prevents (or discourages) duplicates. But in case of suggested edits, I have no other choice but to leave the question as it is - i.e. with those tags in the title.

I am suggesting that, we remove the validation (shown above) from the "Suggested Edits" queue. This will allow the reviewers to edit out the fluff if they consider it appropriate.

We could go a step further, and remove this particular validation for all 2k+ users.

Comment: should you be voting to close one as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: @RobertLongson I am not sure of this case. I don't have much experience with CORS issues. I assume that methods to mitigate CORS issues may be different in different frameworks.

Comment: @RobertLongson not always; I had a generic case of someone wanting to interchange array elements in a specific manner in MATLAB, and the title without tags was already used for the same problem, but in C++.

Comment: @Adriaan That's why I asked a question rather than making a statement. I'm not proposing a general rule just something to consider if you find yourself in that position.

Comment: @RobertLongson I only vote on duplicates if they are both within MATLAB (the only thing I speak); so I would not be comfortable with dupe voting, especially when they go across languages which is certainly not a duplicate, with anything outside my expertise. I'd drop it in the SOCVR in the hope someone there speaks the language.

Comment: I don't see that there's a question here

Answer (score 1):

You see a lot of this, people ask a question, get the warning, then proceed by adding fluff to the title, usually tags or something else superfluous.

When you come to edit the fluff out, you see the warning they worked their way around by adding the fluff.

If it is a dupe, then close it as such and ignore the title, which you can't do much about.

There's plenty that has already been said on the subject, below are a few posts.

**Related reading:**

[Can't edit question - title already exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288001/cant-edit-question-title-already-exists)

[What problem does refusing duplicate titles solve?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317395/what-problem-does-refusing-duplicate-titles-solve)

[Allow editors to submit duplicate titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317393/allow-editors-to-submit-duplicate-titles)

[Should I improve the title of an obvious duplicate? If so, how do I make it more unique?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317364/should-i-improve-the-title-of-an-obvious-duplicate-if-so-how-do-i-make-it-more)

Comment: I am not asking "what to do in such cases". I am suggesting that we remove that validation for users reviewing suggested edits. Perhaps for anyone above 2k, so that they can remove that fluff.

Comment: but then you will get a question with the same title as one that already exists, that is the point of the validation.

Comment: Yup. So do we want to leave the question with the fluff, or are we okay with two questions having the same title? IMO, two questions having the same title is okay, as long as the title is apt for the question.

Comment: @NisargShah see the links i edited in.